# Trying to access AS400/DB2 stored procedure from Java with Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, db2, jdbctemplate

Trying to access AS400/DB2 stored procedure from Java with Spring JdbcTemplate,

```
XmlBeanFactory beanFactory2 = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource(
                "datasource_as400.xml"));
        DataSource ds2 = (DataSource) beanFactory2.getBean("dataSource");

        jdbc2 = new JdbcTemplate(ds2);

        jdbc2.update("{CALL TESTONE(?)}", new Object[] { new String("JOHN") });
```

and I am getting the following Error

```
[DEBUG,SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator] Translating SQLException with SQL state '42704', error code '-204', message [[SQL0204] TESTONE in  type *N not found.]; SQL was [{CALL TESTONE(?)}] for task [PreparedStatementCallback]
[FATAL,MainBatch] processDonations(): org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{CALL TESTONE(?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0204] TESTONE in  type *N not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [iSeries Info Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzala/rzalaccl.htm), SQLCODE `-204` means `An undefined object or constraint name was detected.`

You may have to designate the schema your function is in.  (I.E., `CALL YOUR_SCHEMA.TESTONE(?)`).

If it works in another program (or when you query manually), your schema path may be set differently.  You can check by doing `SELECT CURRENT_SCHEMA FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`  (I'm not sure if `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` is on iSeries, or if there is another name for the dummy table... I'm used to z/OS or Linux/Unix/Windows DB2).

Comment: Another idea is perhaps your procedure is expecting a certain data type coming in, and Spring is sending it in as another type?  In which case, you can add a `CAST(? AS type)` to your parameter.  Sometimes DB2 can be picky about data types in procedures.